# Java List String sort Based on Integer with multiple underscore's

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections, java-8

Hi All I have arrayList of String datatype but needs to sort like integer with multiple underscore's using **Java 8** only ,For your reference I have added sample data, the original data came Liferay 7.1 DDL

```
List<String> keyValues = new ArrayList<String>();
keyValues.add("100_10_20_1");
keyValues.add("100001");
keyValues.add("100002");
keyValues.add("100002_1");
keyValues.add("100003");
keyValues.add("100");
keyValues.add("100_1");
keyValues.add("100_2");
keyValues.add("100_1_1");
keyValues.add("100_10_20");
keyValues.add("10000001");
keyValues.add("100_10_20_2");
```

i tried to replace the underscore with 0 but what happens sometimes 100_1 replace _ with 0 then it becomes 10001 but what if i already have 10001 value present in list ? even same thing for empty if i replace _ with "" then it becomes  1001 but what if i already have 1001 then again i am facing issue

**Exact logic based on underscore was**

```
 100
 100_1
 100_1_2 
 /after that only/
 100_2
 100_2_2
/after that/
 103
 104
 105
 10000
/similarly the pattern repeats/
 10000_1
 10000_2
 10000_2_1
 100002
```

i need the exact **output** as

```
    100
    100_1
    100_1_1
    100_2
    100_10_20
    100_10_20_1
    100_10_20_2
    100001
    100002
    100002_1
    100003
    10000001
```

i tried with replacing underscore with 0 or empty space but there is possiblity of if it had already that number present in list,if i replace with dot and storing as Double then multiple pointer exception will occur

Comment: are you sure you want `100_2` before `100_1_1` ? (otherwise you could use something similar to `keyValues.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> Runtime.Version.parse(s.replace("_",".")))).toList()`)

Comment: Hi @user16320675 instead of Runtime.Version.parse any other approach in java 8

Comment: “based on underscores count”—nowhere in your question is a dependency between your intended order and the number of underscores explained. In fact, there is no attempt to explain the intended order at all. If you only want that exact output you have shown, just add the strings in that order. If you want a general solution, you have to explain the intended logic behind it.

Comment: Hi @Holger i have updated the question and answer but it needs to occur only java 8

Comment: You still didn’t describe the *intended logic* behind the result order.

Comment: Providing a single example is not describing the general logic behind the result. Inserting “after that” does not improve anything; we already know what comes after what in your single example. Software has to work even if you don’t know the actual input at compile-time. Can you explain *without referring to your example*, what the software is supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a comparator then split the string and process based on the min amount of tokens each string has.

```
static Comparator<String> stringComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            String[] s1 = o1.split("_");
            String[] s2 = o2.split("_");

            int minLen = Math.min(s1.length, s2.length);

            for (int i=0; i < minLen; i++){
                if (!s1[i].equals(s2[i])){
                    return Integer.parseInt(s1[i]) - Integer.parseInt(s2[i]);
//                    return s1[i].compareTo(s2[i]);  //not natural order/sort
                }
            }

            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    };
```

Calling it like so:

```
    List<String> keyValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    keyValues.add("100001");
    keyValues.add("100002");
    keyValues.add("100002_1");
    keyValues.add("100003");
    keyValues.add("100");
    keyValues.add("100_1");
    keyValues.add("100_2");
    keyValues.add("100_1_1");
    keyValues.add("100_10_20");
    keyValues.add("10000001");
    keyValues.stream().sorted(stringComparator).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Gives output:

```
100
100_1
100_1_1
100_2
100_10_20
100001
100002
100002_1
100003
10000001
```